# import string date to another format in pandas

Tags: pandas, string, datetime

how can I import the string date in format %Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S to date time format?
I tried as below but it does not work, in fact x.day should give 8 and 9, not 6 (6 is the month day)

```
pd.to_datetime(new_data.time, format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
Out[51]: 
0       2021-08-06 20:55:15
1       2021-08-06 20:55:16
2       2021-08-06 20:55:17
3       2021-08-06 20:55:20
4       2021-08-06 20:55:21
       
10798   2021-09-06 07:18:51
10799   2021-09-06 07:18:54
10800   2021-09-06 07:19:56
10801   2021-09-06 07:20:00
10802   2021-09-06 07:20:02
Name: time, Length: 10803, dtype: datetime64[ns]

pd.to_datetime(new_data.time, format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S').apply(lambda x: x.day)
Out[52]: 
0        6
1        6
2        6
3        6
4        6
        ..
10798    6
10799    6
10800    6
10801    6
10802    6
Name: time, Length: 10803, dtype: int64
```

edit 1 - try 1:I changed the format as suggestedin the answer but no success. I also added for more clarity the original content of the data series

```
new_data.time
Out[56]: 
0       2021-08-06 20:55:15
1       2021-08-06 20:55:16
2       2021-08-06 20:55:17
3       2021-08-06 20:55:20
4       2021-08-06 20:55:21
       
10798   2021-09-06 07:18:51
10799   2021-09-06 07:18:54
10800   2021-09-06 07:19:56
10801   2021-09-06 07:20:00
10802   2021-09-06 07:20:02
Name: time, Length: 10803, dtype: datetime64[ns]

pd.to_datetime(new_data.time, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').apply(lambda x: x.day)
Out[57]: 
0        6
1        6
2        6
3        6
4        6
        ..
10798    6
10799    6
10800    6
10801    6
10802    6
Name: time, Length: 10803, dtype: int64
```

I reopen the topic because of error when in the column appear more than one day date (I believe this is the root cause). PLease see the code below:

```
new_data=pandas.read_clipboard(thousands='.', decimal=',',names=['date','time','price','price2','price3','price4','var','volume'])

new_data
Out[145]: 
          date      time    price   price2   price3   price4   var  volume
0     31/08/21  00:00:00  1.17943  1.17965  1.17940  1.17964  0.00       0
1     31/08/21  00:01:00  1.17963  1.17974  1.17962  1.17973  0.01       0
2     31/08/21  00:02:00  1.17974  1.17977  1.17973  1.17976  0.00       0
3     31/08/21  00:03:00  1.17976  1.17976  1.17975  1.17975  0.00       0
4     31/08/21  00:04:00  1.17974  1.17979  1.17974  1.17978  0.00       0
       ...       ...      ...      ...      ...      ...   ...     ...
2300  01/09/21  16:31:00  1.18429  1.18451  1.18418  1.18451  0.02       0
2301  01/09/21  16:32:00  1.18451  1.18465  1.18448  1.18464  0.01       0
2302  01/09/21  16:33:00  1.18463  1.18477  1.18459  1.18460  0.00       0
2303  01/09/21  16:34:00  1.18459  1.18464  1.18446  1.18464  0.00       0
2304  01/09/21  16:35:02  1.18449  1.18450  1.18449  1.18450 -0.01       0

[2305 rows x 8 columns]

new_data.time=(new_data.date+';'+new_data.time)

new_data
Out[147]: 
          date               time    price  ...   price4   var  volume
0     31/08/21  31/08/21;00:00:00  1.17943  ...  1.17964  0.00       0
1     31/08/21  31/08/21;00:01:00  1.17963  ...  1.17973  0.01       0
2     31/08/21  31/08/21;00:02:00  1.17974  ...  1.17976  0.00       0
3     31/08/21  31/08/21;00:03:00  1.17976  ...  1.17975  0.00       0
4     31/08/21  31/08/21;00:04:00  1.17974  ...  1.17978  0.00       0
       ...                ...      ...  ...      ...   ...     ...
2300  01/09/21  01/09/21;16:31:00  1.18429  ...  1.18451  0.02       0
2301  01/09/21  01/09/21;16:32:00  1.18451  ...  1.18464  0.01       0
2302  01/09/21  01/09/21;16:33:00  1.18463  ...  1.18460  0.00       0
2303  01/09/21  01/09/21;16:34:00  1.18459  ...  1.18464  0.00       0
2304  01/09/21  01/09/21;16:35:02  1.18449  ...  1.18450 -0.01       0

[2305 rows x 8 columns]

pandas.to_datetime(new_data.time.astype(str), format='%Y/%m/%d;%H:%M:%S')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 456, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)

  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 350, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-148-cdb9c84e99e7>", line 1, in <module>
    pandas.to_datetime(new_data.time.astype(str), format='%Y/%m/%d;%H:%M:%S')

  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 805, in to_datetime
    values = convert_listlike(arg._values, format)

  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 460, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    raise e

  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 424, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    arg, format, exact=exact, errors=errors

  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx", line 144, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime

ValueError: time data '31/08/21;00:00:00' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d;%H:%M:%S' (match)
```

any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It means in original column are swapped `d <-> m`, so need change:

```
pd.to_datetime(new_data.time, format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
```

to:

```
pd.to_datetime(new_data.time, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

If month is before `day`, also working only:

```
pd.to_datetime(new_data.time)
```

EDIT:

Problem is there are already datetimes before `to_datetime`, so pandas not convert.

You can convert values to strings for converting again (but it means all datetimes is possible convert, else raise error):

```
pd.to_datetime(new_data.time.astype(str), format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')
```

Possible solution for converting with `NaT` for not convertiable datetimes:

```
pd.to_datetime(new_data.time.astype(str), format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S', erros='coerce')
```

Comment: @realbro - ibn question missing what is `print (new_data.time)` before `pd.to_datetime(new_data.time, format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')`, can you add it to question?

Comment: I modified the question adding more detail about the original series

Comment: topic reopen uinfortunately... thanks if you help again